# Show the amount of posts in a tag in a specific category has

Tags: wordpress, tags, categories

I am creating a page template in Wordpress that displays multiple tags that are in a particular category. I have this working, but now I want to have the number of posts within each tag that is displayed as well like if I had a tag called apples with 5 posts it would look like this:

```
Apples(5)
```

As of now it just shows `Apples`

Here is my code I want to modify:

```
    <?php
      if (is_category()){
           $cat = get_query_var('cat');
           $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
       }
       $tag_IDs = array();
           query_posts('category_name=health');
                   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                       $posttags = get_the_tags();
                           if ($posttags):
                           foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                               if (!in_array($tag->term_id , $tag_IDs)):
                                   $tag_IDs[] = $tag->term_id;
                                   $tag_names[$tag->term_id] = $tag->name;
                                   endif;
                       }
                       endif;
                       endwhile; endif;
                   wp_reset_query();
       
               echo "<ul>";
               foreach($tag_IDs as $tag_ID){
               echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag_ID).'">'.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'</a>';
               }
           echo "</ul>";
       ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the following:

Outside the loop for the current query:

```
<?php echo $wp_query->get_queried_object()->count; ?>
```

Inside the loop for each terms:

```
<?php echo $tag->count; ?>
```

Regards.